# Returning contents of file after deletion as new file download

Tags: php

I have two php functions that are called upon consecutive requestes:

This is called on the first request:

```
public static function ProcessResponseFile($request_file_content)
{
    session_start();
    $temp_file = tempnam("./tmp", "file"); 
    file_put_contents($temp_file, $request_file_content);
    $_SESSION['request_response'] = $temp_file;
    return file_get_contents($temp_file);
}
```

The following function is called on the second request:

```
public static function GetResponseFileContent()
{
    session_start(); 
    $filename = $_SESSION['request_response'];
    $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
    $response_content = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
    fclose($handle);
   // $response_content = file_get_contents($_SESSION['request_response']);
    unlink($_SESSION['request_response']);
    unset($_SESSION['request_response']);
    return $response_content;
}
```

The `$response_content` is empty. If I comment the unlink and unset, I get the appropriate file contents. 
Why is that ?

I want to download the returned value of **GetResponseFileContent()**

```
if (isset($_POST['submit_download'])) {

    ob_end_clean();
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=raspuns.xml");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream; "); 
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

    session_start();
    echo Application::GetResponseFileContent();

}
```

Comment: What if you just comment one of those lines, but not both?

Comment: Same thing happens for any combination of comment upon those 2 lines but still I want to do them both, clear the session variable and delete the file.

Comment: I was just trying to figure out what the dependency is, not suggesting it as a fix. I don't understand how either of them can have an effect on a variable that's assigned before them. What happens if you echo the variable before and after the `unlink/unset`?

Comment: Ok, same thing happens, I want to download the returned value into a file.

Comment: I'm stumped. I can't think of any way that deleting a file **after** reading from it can empty the variable.

Comment: What do you see if you `echo filesize($filename)` at the beginning of `GetResponseFileContent`?

Comment: I have changed the last piece of code in the question and commented the header() calls and correct content of the file showed correctly on the webpage. My intention is to download that into a file.

Comment: Did you call `ob_start()` earlier in script?

Comment: That was it, now it works. Post it as answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you can use `ob_end_clean()`, you have to use `ob_start()`. Otherwise, there's no output buffer to clear out.